# Will I be stuck with the same parents and family forever in Jannah?

Tags: halal-haram, jannah

I was wondering will parents and family be the same in Jannah as it was here in the Dunya? What if I don't want to ever see my family or parents for eternity? Can I have that choice? Will Allah grant me this? I want to serve Allah and be free and happy without them. I don't want them to recognize me. Or I to recognize them.

Answer (score 1):

The thing you need to realize is, no person will ever be the same person as they were in this world in paradise.

So the family you dislike or hate may be the same people, but more appealing to you.

There will be no hatred, envy, jealousy, anger, etc. in paradise so all the grudges, family conflicts you’ve had in this world will no longer exist in paradise.

The family you once hated won’t be the same type of people you knew in this world once you Inshallah see them in heaven. So you don’t have to worry about hating them or wanting new people because while they will be the same people, their personalities will be different, everyone will be much kinder towards each other.

Comment: Thank you for answering this question. But can I still get what I want? Like in Jannah you get whatever you want. I have this strong hunch that I don't want to see them even in Jannah. Maybe once and that is it. I don't love them. And I know that will not send me to hell. In Jannah you can be with people who you like, not people who you don't love. Maybe they will be different but I still will get whatever I really really truly want.

Comment: @Mildred Yes you can get whatever you desire in Hannah. I don’t know your situation, but according to the rules of Jannah, the enemy of yours will be your friend in Jannah. So while you hate them here, you’ll view them in a while nother perspective in Jannah. But to answer your question, yes you can have whatever you wish.

Comment: Another intimate question, I am Indian but before I was created I wanted to be another race (white). I did not want to be Indian or brown. In Jannah can I get to be white? Can I be a completely new person with a new soul, new character etc? I know that in Jannah we will get a perfect brain, soul, body and character. And can I wish for a new family? I know family will be different in Jannah than it was here in Dunya. We are going to live in the akirah forever, I want to be who I truly wanted to be. I can't change anything because Allah is in control, he created it this way.

Comment: @Mildred Allahu A’lam

Comment: there was no text or comment.

Comment: @Mildred what do you mean?

Comment: Can you answer my "another intimate question" post? I want to know if it is possible for me to be another race as well. I believe it is not fair that Allah chose what race and nationality we would be born into. It's not fair the family or parents Allah chose me to be in. My family is abusive so I was wondering if I could be another race and get a new family in Jannah if I wish and it will be granted.

Comment: @Mildred Allah knows best to your question. All I know is, in Jannah, you can get whatever your heart desires. I’m sure someone more fitting to answer your question.